# obtain information from "My Profile"

Tags: android

I need to get the data "my profile" to know the cell phone owner's name.

I know how to get the email but I need name or alias.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private String getUserProfileName()
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cur.moveToNext())
    {
        int isUser = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Profile.IS_USER_PROFILE));   
        if (isUser > 0)
        {
            isNewContact = false;
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Profile.DISPLAY_NAME));                    
            Log.e(TAG, "user profile name " + name);
            cur.close();
            return name;
        }
    }  

    Log.e(TAG, "no user profile found!");
    cur.close();
    isNewContact = true;
    return null;
}
```

Make sure to add the permission to your AndroidManifest file: `android.permission.READ_PROFILE`